# Bootstrap Close Alerts JavaScript Not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a **Close Alerts option**, but it's not working correctly. I'm using all of script but it does not work.

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#" class="close"  aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Thanks</strong>Lets Do it
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the data-dismiss="alert" in the close link. It should work with the following:

```
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
```